# Celery works with local broker url but not with a url from CloudAMQP

Tags: python, flask, celery, amqp, cloudamqp

I'm using Celery to handle background tasks in my flask app and I have troubles making it work with CloudAMQP

```
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config["BROKER_URL"],
            backend="amqp://"
            )
```

where the broker url is `amqp://ali:**@127.0.0.1:5672//`
 for local usage and `amqp://name:password@moose.rmq.cloudamqp.com/name` for production

I tried to use CloudAMQP locally and this is the log

```
[2016-03-22 16:47:16,919: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://name:password@moose.rmq.cloudamqp.com/name
[2016-03-22 16:47:16,937: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-03-22 16:47:17,958: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-03-22 16:47:17,989: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@alidesktop ready.
```

After that nothing happens; tasks are not executed
but after I return to the local broker url, queued tasks execute normally.

Comment: looks like you're connecting just fine. have you queued up and tasks?

Comment: have the same problem with wascally [rabbot] and nodejs